# America based company or American based company

Tags: adjectives, hyphens

I'm surprised to see, that there is no complete agreement on the interwebs on which form is correct. Do we place the *based* after the nation or the country? E.g. is it

South Africa based company or South African based company?

America based company or American based company? etc.

I'd think it's obvious that we want to express the home-country of the company, so we use the country.

Answer (score 1):

American means "of America" so applying based in this context is superfluous.

America-based would be more appropriate, but US-based would likely sound/read better.